# Let $S_ 0$ be the space with $2$ points and the discrete topology. Find [$S_ 0$ , $X$] for an arbitrary space $X$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $S_
0$ be the space with $2$ points and the discrete topology. Find [$S_
0$
, $X$] for an
arbitrary space $X$. $[X,Y]=\{f:X\to Y,f$ continuous $\}/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the homotopic equivalence.

I have only proved that if $X$ is contractible then [$S_
0$
, $X$] is singleton & if $p_1,P_2\in X$ be connected by a path then $\bar C_{p_1}=\bar C_{p_2}$ where $C_{p_1}(x)=p_1 \forall x\in S^0$. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have two maps $f,g\colon S^0 \to X$, what is a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ (assume that they are homotopic)?

Comment: Don't know. There might be $H(x,t)$, but what is the explicit form of that?

Comment: I'm not after an explicit form (for an abstract $X$, we couldn't have that anyway). By definition, a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ is - what?

Comment: Ok, it is a continuous map from $X \times I \to Y$ s.t $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$.

Comment: Well, in principle. Here, our domain space is $S^0$ and the target space is called $X$, but that should not lead to insurmountable confusion. So, what does $S^0\times I$ look like?

Comment: The graph will be two $[0,1]$ strip on two points. May be..Will you give me the answer.

Comment: We're getting close. $S^0\times I$ basically consists of two disjoint copies of $I$ which have nothing really to do with each other. So what the homotopy does for the point $-1$ and what it does for $1$ (I call the two points of $S^0$ thus) are unrelated things. Now, what is $t\mapsto H(1,t)$? And what is $t\mapsto H(-1,t)$?

Comment: Both are continuous map. And $I$ being connected $H(1,t)$ is connected.

Comment: $t↦H(1,t)$ is also a cont map.

Comment: And a continuous map $I\to X$ is called how?

Comment: Sorry.... did not get your point.

Comment: A path in $X$. So $t\mapsto H(1,t)$ is a path in $X$ connecting which points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S^0 = \{1,-1\}$. Then $S^0 \times I = \{1,-1\}\times I = \{1\} \times I \cup \{-1\} \times I$ is basically a disjoint union of two copies of the unit interval $I$. Hence a homotopy $H$ between two maps $f,g \colon S^0 \to X$ "consists" of two paths in $X$, one, $t\mapsto H(1,t)$, connecting $f(1)$ and $g(1)$, the other, $t \mapsto H(-1,t)$, connecting $f(-1)$ and $g(-1)$.

Conversely, if $\alpha\colon I \to X$ is a path connecting $f(1)$ to $g(1)$, and $\beta\colon I \to X$ is a path connecting $f(-1)$ to $g(-1)$, then we get a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ by setting

$$H(1,t) = \alpha(t),\quad H(-1,t) = \beta(t).$$

So $f$ and $g$ are homotopic if and only if $f(1)$ can be connected to $g(1)$ by a path and $f(-1)$ can be connected to $g(-1)$ by a path. In other words, if and only if $f(p)$ and $g(p)$ lie in the same path component of $X$ for every $p\in S^0$.

This gives a bijection between $[S^0,X]$ and the set of ordered pairs of path components of $X$ via that map $f \mapsto (C(f(1)), C(f(-1)))$, where $C(x)$ denotes the path component of $x$ in $X$.